# SSH login callback/Interceptor for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, google-authenticator

I want to implement a multi-user ssh authentication so whenever a user ssh logs in via either password or private/public key then my script get's initiated automatically and it takes control to further authorize some second tier validations like Google Authenticator does.

So How can I intercept SSH login success and run my own script to ask user for further authentication before allowing him to get access of the system.

So how exactly Google Authenticator intercept ssh session to ask for code verification??

I am trying to implement a GA like application with enhanced feature set.

Comment: You could implement a PAM module for MFA. See http://www.linux-pam.org/

Comment: Thank you peter but how I'll implement MFA for public/private key based SSH ? ssh does not use PAM for key based authentication

Comment: You need to configure SSH like this `AuthenticationMethods publickey,password`. This way you need to provide a password after the public key auth. This password can be your MFA token.